# Add CSS and JS files of the template post on a WordPress page

Tags: posts, pages

Out of necessity I should add all the CSS and JS files present in any WordPress article on a specific page through code.

Do you know how to add all these files?

If I try through the normal `get_header()` code, the necessary files are added for the page and not for the articles, as it should normally be.

I would like to make this change because I embed an article on a page and the codes of a plugin are not presented if the page is not actually read as an article.

Thanks a lot to those who will help me.

This is the answer I get if I try to add files after files, that is, all CSS and JS

[image]

Comment: So the page you're mentioning is not a page created a wp page but an extra page with a physical file? otherwise, if it's a wp page, the  .js and .css files should be enqueued, except if some plugins are enqueuing scripts and styles only for specific post_types..

Comment: Surely the plugin in question queues for post_types. How can I do? And anyway yes, my pages are all personalized but they use the basic WordPress code.

Comment: the screenshot shows js errors that can depend on other issues, check the source code of your page and see in `<head>`  tag if the needed styles and scripts are present. In this case the enqueuing is ok but the errors are caused by the .js themselves. `CodeMirror is not defined` is likely to means that a some more scripts are missing. Also important the order with wich you enqueue the scripts. `CodeMirror` evidently must be defined before it can be used

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's file functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','STACK_356524_add_css_js_on_page',99);
function STACK_356524_add_css_js_on_page(){
  global $post;
  if($post->post_type=='page') {  // check if the current wp object is a `page` also is_page() can be used: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js_handler', 'url_of_your_script', array(), '' );
    wp_enqueue_style('css_handler','url_of_your_style',array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
  }
}
```

Up to you adjust the correct path to the .css and .js you need to enqueue, you can have a look at the source page where the scripts and files are present and use that string.
More granular adjustment can be done ( versioning, dependencies -I.E. jquery or even enqueue only on specific pages -i.e: `if( post->ID ==12345){}`.

For more info:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

(IT) https://softrade.it/WP/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have previously tried this answer to insert code after code but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: this must work, if there are issues can be surely solved

Comment: I updated the ticket, I see the problems shown in the image.

Comment: except if in your page template you don't use `get_header()`, in this case that will not work

Comment: I confirm that get_header () is on the page.

Perhaps the problem may be due to the fact that the article code calls it from an AJAX request?

Comment: I tried to add the various files also with the HTML tags <script> and <link> but nothing at all, the error is always the same.